# Ionic sideMenu ios issue with iframe

Tags: ios, iframe, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic App with latest version and have and issue on IOS.

My App have a view that loads an external URL on an iframe and a sideMenu with several options.

When i open the sideMenu on IOS, the iframe scroll to top and show cut off, with more than 50% of the bottom iframe in white. On Android works fine.

I tried to use resize, i tried to modify the CSS and also tried all the properties of the ion-content, ion-view and ion-sideMenus.

Any suggestion or idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it!

Following that

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1151

It works correctly now!